# Complete this well-known phrase or saying - about van Gogh?

Tags: riddle

**Complete this well-known phrase or saying**

-----, --- ----- --------

(5), (3, 5, 8)

---

**Clues**

(i) One of these was left when van Gogh removed the left.

(ii) He didn't have this, I hear, to use as a replacement.

Comment: [cryptic-clues] refers specifically to a certain type of crossword clue. That seems to not be what's going on here, so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **Space, the final frontier** - a quote from the [introductory narration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_no_man_has_gone_before) of *Star Trek* episodes. The narration in full:
>
>  *Space: the final frontier. These are the voyages of the starship Enterprise. Its five-year mission: to explore strange new worlds. To seek out new life and new civilizations. To boldly go where no man has gone before!*

Explanation of clues:

*(i) One of these was left when van Gogh removed the left.*

> A **space** was *left* behind when Vincent van Gogh [cut off his left ear](https://www.vangoghmuseum.nl/en/art-and-stories/vincent-van-gogh-faq/why-did-vincent-van-gogh-cut-off-his-ear) ('*removed the left*') after an argument with Paul Gauguin.

*(ii) He didn't have this, I hear, to use as a replacement.*

> **INCOMING PUN WARNING!**
>  Unfortunately for van Gogh, he only had a left ear and a right ear and the right one was pretty fixed in place on the other side of his head. If, however, he had also had **a final front ear** he might have been able to use that *as a replacement* for the one he had just removed... (The pun here is that 'frontier' sounds like 'front ear'.)

Comment: Correct of course!